# SSL client and server certificates used to restrict server access to specific machines

Tags: ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I am investigating the use of SSL to ensure security when performing remote software updates to embedded systems. This means that I would like to ensure that only specific client machines may communicate with the embedded server system.

I understand that server certificates authenticate the identity of the server and client certificates authenticate the identity of the client and this prevents man in the middle attacks.

What I would like to know is if client certificates can be used in such a way that only clients with specific certificates, compatible with the server, can communicate with the server.

My interpretation so far from reading up on this is that that certificates are used to ensure that either client or server are who they say they are. Not to restrict access to specific clients. Is this correct?

If someone could help clarify this, and provide some pointers, I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: "that certificates are used to ensure that either client or server are who they say they are." as a first step, but then you can completely, on each side, restrict which certificates or CA you want to accept. See this example in Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire  But at this stage your question is too broad and not related programming related, so off topic here.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Can you explain how my questions are broad please? "What I would like to know is if client certificates can be used in such a way that only clients with specific certificates, compatible with the server, can communicate with the server." This is a specific question requiring a yes/no answer.   So is the following "My interpretation so far from reading up on this is that that certificates are used to ensure that either client or server are who they say they are. Not to restrict access to specific clients. Is this correct?"

Comment: "This is a specific question requiring a yes/no answer. " It is yes, I gave you an example, but the question is still too broad: which clients? which servers? which constraints? etc. So the answer is more "maybe" depending on which client, which server, which contraints, etc. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and specifically the 4 bullet points at beginning. See also bullet point number "4." covering your last sentence about pointers. Note the "and what has been done so far to solve it." which is exactly what is missing from your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'll try to rephrase the question. I'm not sure how to answer 'which client?' and 'which server?' Most of the material I've read on this subject simply talk about clients and servers and the mechanisms in place to ensure certification and authentication, so I guess my question relates to understanding these mechanism.

Comment: "which client" and "which server" in YOUR case. This is exactly why your question is too vague: you do not concentrate on your specific problem, you are just asking if something is possible in general sense. Yes it is , or maybe, it depends on specific conditions. Which needs to be given to be discussed. "so I guess my question relates to understanding these mechanism. " which by definition is not a programming question then... But in general, in any exchange, any party is free to use any information known on the other party to decide how to discuss or not with it. This works for TLS or others